Appserver for 32bit in OpenEdge 12.8
I have a 32-bit GUI on-premises application currently running on OpenEdge 11.7 that uses AppServer. I am planning to upgrade to OpenEdge 12.8 (32-bit) but have noticed that PASOE is only available in the 64-bit version of OpenEdge 12.8. How can I configure AppServer or achieve equivalent functionality in OpenEdge 12.8 (32-bit)

Which code running on your AppServer needs to be 32-bit?

Like you said - PASOE (the only AppServer in OpenEdge 12.8) is only available as a 64 bit product.
If you're client needs to be 32 bit (why?) - you need to install Client Networking or Web Client in 32 bit and the AppServer product in 64 bit. You can install both products on the same machine in parallel directories.
The 32 bit client can access the 64 bit AppServer without limitations.

My client has a large number of OCX files that rely on a 32-bit setup. Replacing them would almost amount to rebuilding the entire UI, which is quite a task. So, it’s more practical to keep the 32-bit client as it is for now.
